# PCM audio in MP4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

Why is it written in the standard that PCM in mp4 is not supported, but Sony cameras (for example A7s) somehow know how to do it. Does it violate the standard?How did they manage to do it?

Answer (score 0):

MP4 is a variation of the MOV container, which itself can have PCM audio specified in the metadata. For example when processing MP4 bytes I will [reference the MOV specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH205-BBCGEBEH).

1. It's possible that your MP4 is really just a MOV file renamed as a `.mp4`.
2. If the playing side knows to expect PCM (*eg:* Don't assume the incoming numbers are AAC data) then its no problem with using PCM in the MP4 container. You could safely replace all AAC bytes with PCM bytes.
3. It doesn't break the standard as far as MOV is concerned, but MPEG decoders usually only want to see MPEG codecs (h.264 / h.265 / MP3 / AAC) in an MPEG-4 file. Some will accept such a PCM containing file, some may refuse to play it. Some coders are even putting VP8/VP9 video codec inside MP4 these days.